# oracle 11g execution plan behaviour

Tags: oracle11g, sql-execution-plan

I have this very simple query performing filtering and join by rowid.

```
SELECT *
FROM  BOOKING.BOOKING_GRID BG,
  BOOKING.BOOKING_STATES BS
WHERE BG.hotel=128
AND BS.ROWID =BG.BOOKINGSTATE;
```

when I explain plan I get:

```
PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Plan hash value: 1597031677                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------                                                                                                                                                                                                           
| Id  | Operation          | Name                | Rows  | Bytes |TempSpc| Cost (%CPU)| Time     |                                                                                                                                                                                                           
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------                                                                                                                                                                                                           
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT   |                     |  6137K|  1041M|       |  1763K  (1)| 05:48:27 |                                                                                                                                                                                                           
|*  1 |  HASH JOIN         |                     |  6137K|  1041M|   538M|  1763K  (1)| 05:48:27 |                                                                                                                                                                                                           
|*  2 |   INDEX UNIQUE SCAN| BOOKING_GRIDPK      |  6137K|   468M|       |   547K  (1)| 01:48:05 |                                                                                                                                                                                                           
|*  3 |    INDEX RANGE SCAN| BOOKING_GRID_INDEX5 |  6137K|       |       | 90388   (1)| 00:17:52 |                                                                                                                                                                                                           
|   4 |   TABLE ACCESS FULL| BOOKING_STATES      |   158M|    14G|       |   365K  (2)| 01:12:14 |                                                                                                                                                                                                           
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------                                                                                                                                                                                                           

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
---------------------------------------------------                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          

   1 - access("BS".ROWID="BG"."BOOKINGSTATE")                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
   2 - access("BG"."HOTEL"=128)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
   3 - access("BG"."HOTEL"=128)
```

Index for BOOKING_GRID are:

```
BOOKING BOOKING_GRIDPK  UNIQUE  VALID   IOT - TOP   N   NO      NO  HOTEL, DAY, BOOKINGSTATE
BOOKING BOOKING_GRID_UNIQ   UNIQUE  VALID   NORMAL  N   NO      NO  HOTEL, DAY, BOOKING, VALIDITYSTART
BOOKING BOOKING_GRID_INDEX5 NONUNIQUE   VALID   NORMAL  N   NO      NO  HOTEL, BOOKINGSTATUS, ISDAYUSE, DAY
BOOKING BOOKING_GRID_INDEX7 NONUNIQUE   VALID   NORMAL  N   NO      NO  HOTEL, BOOKING, VALIDITYSTART
BOOKING BOOKING_GRID_INDEX10    NONUNIQUE   VALID   NORMAL  N   NO      NO  HOTEL, ISDAYUSE, BOOKINGSTATUS, DAY
```

Index for BOOKING_STATES are:

```
BOOKING BOOKING_STATES_PK   UNIQUE  VALID   NORMAL  N   NO      NO  HOTEL, BOOKING, VALIDITYSTART   
BOOKING BOOKING_STATES_INDEX2   NONUNIQUE   VALID   NORMAL  N   NO      NO  HOTEL, YIELDROOMTYPE, BOOKEDROOMTYPE, ROOMTYPE  
BOOKING BOOKING_STATES_BOOKING  NONUNIQUE   VALID   NORMAL  N   NO      NO  HOTEL, BOOKING, BOOKINGSTATUS   
BOOKING BOOKING_NOSEGMENT_INDEX NONUNIQUE   VALID   FUNCTION-BASED NORMAL   N   NO  ENABLED NO  SYS_NC00034$    TO_NUMBER(DECODE(TO_CHAR("MARKETSEGMENT"),NULL,DECODE("BOOK",0,NULL,TO_CHAR(DECODE("ISDAYUSE",'N',DECODE("ISSHARED",'N',DECODE("BOOKINGSTATUS",'B',"HOTEL"*10000+LEAST("DEPARTURE","VALIDITYEND"),'I',"HOTEL"*10000+LEAST("DEPARTURE","VALIDITYEND"),'W',"HOTEL"*10000+LEAST("DEPARTURE","VALIDITYEND"))))))))
BOOKING BOOKING_NORATE_CODE_INDEX   NONUNIQUE   VALID   FUNCTION-BASED NORMAL   N   NO  ENABLED NO  SYS_NC00033$    TO_NUMBER(DECODE(TO_CHAR("RATECODE"),NULL,DECODE("BOOK",0,NULL,TO_CHAR(DECODE("ISDAYUSE",'N',DECODE("ISSHARED",'N',DECODE("BOOKINGSTATUS",'B',"HOTEL"*10000+LEAST("DEPARTURE","VALIDITYEND"),'I',"HOTEL"*10000+LEAST("DEPARTURE","VALIDITYEND"),'W',"HOTEL"*10000+LEAST("DEPARTURE","VALIDITYEND"))))))))
BOOKING BOOKING_NOBOOKINGTYPE_INDEX NONUNIQUE   VALID   FUNCTION-BASED NORMAL   N   NO  ENABLED NO  SYS_NC00032$    TO_NUMBER(DECODE(TO_CHAR("BOOKINGTYPE"),NULL,DECODE("BOOK",0,NULL,TO_CHAR(DECODE("ISDAYUSE",'N',DECODE("ISSHARED",'N',DECODE("BOOKINGSTATUS",'B',"HOTEL"*10000+LEAST("DEPARTURE","VALIDITYEND"))))))))
BOOKING BOOKING_STATES_BOOKING_TYPE NONUNIQUE   VALID   NORMAL  N   NO      NO  HOTEL, BOOKINGTYPE, ISDAYUSE, BOOKINGSTATUS 
BOOKING BOOKING_STATES_CANCEL_INDEX NONUNIQUE   VALID   FUNCTION-BASED NORMAL   N   NO  ENABLED NO  SYS_NC00035$, SYS_NC00036$  DECODE("BOOKINGSTATUS",'c',"HOTEL",'C',"HOTEL")
BOOKING BOOKING_STATES_CANCEL_INDEX NONUNIQUE   VALID   FUNCTION-BASED NORMAL   N   NO  ENABLED NO  SYS_NC00035$, SYS_NC00036$  DECODE("BOOKINGSTATUS",'c',"CANCELREASON",'C',"CANCELREASON")
```

I don't understand two things:

1. why Oracle would decide it is faster to join before filtering on hotel=128?
2. why using a hash join when it could use a "TABLE ACCESS BY USER ROWID"

The weird thing is that when I run the same exact request with hotel=201, it is perfectly fine:

```
PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Plan hash value: 4251203092                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  

---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------                                                                                                                                                                                                          
| Id  | Operation                   | Name                | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |                                                                                                                                                                                                          
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------                                                                                                                                                                                                          
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT            |                     |   591K|   100M|   643K  (1)| 02:07:12 |                                                                                                                                                                                                          
|   1 |  NESTED LOOPS               |                     |   591K|   100M|   643K  (1)| 02:07:12 |                                                                                                                                                                                                          
|*  2 |   INDEX UNIQUE SCAN         | BOOKING_GRIDPK      |   591K|    45M| 52686   (1)| 00:10:25 |                                                                                                                                                                                                          
|*  3 |    INDEX RANGE SCAN         | BOOKING_GRID_INDEX5 |   591K|       |  8707   (1)| 00:01:44 |                                                                                                                                                                                                          
|   4 |   TABLE ACCESS BY USER ROWID| BOOKING_STATES      |     1 |    98 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |                                                                                                                                                                                                          
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------                                                                                                                                                                                                          

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
---------------------------------------------------                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          

   2 - access("BG"."HOTEL"=201)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
   3 - access("BG"."HOTEL"=201)
```

Any idea about what's going on there?

Thank you,

Renaud

Comment: Of course any peace of advice about how to investigate by myself are welcome :). I tried to dig into V$SQL_PLAN but I didn't really get how to grab information from it.

Comment: What does BG.BOOKINGSTATE represent?  Why is it being compared to ROWID?

Comment: Yes, Oracle provides a way to store physical rowid (supposed to be the fastest way to join) under the condition they can never change (this is a setting in the DB). This is what we did, BG.bookingstate is the rowid of a row in BS.

Comment: How do you guarantee that a rowid can never change? Are you never going to want to move a table to a new tablespace, shrink it to recover space, move to a new server, copy this data to a development/test/qa server, partition the table, use table flashback etc? Tell you what, in 20 years I've never seen anyone implement rowid's as a permanent key value. Even worse in your case, you are seeing hash joins in which any performance benefits of avoiding the rowid lookup through an index are negated - in fact performance might even be worse with a rowid because it is larger than a numeric key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for the different execution paths is because Oracle thinks that there are about 6 million rows with hotel=128 but only 591,000 with hotel=201. In the case of the bigger intermediate set, Oracle chose a hash join over nested loops.

What I don't get is this:

```
AND BS.ROWID =BG.BOOKINGSTATE;
```

You're storing Oracle-format ROWIDs in a column called BOOKINGSTATE???

---

Ok, given your confirmation that BOOKINGSTATE really does contain Oracle ROWIDs, here's why I'd say you're getting a HASH JOIN instead of a NESTED LOOP join:

First, when Oracle reads a row, it doesn't just read a row at a time, it reads blocks at a time. So to do a NESTED LOOP join with a TABLE ACCESS BY USER ROWID lookup, it's going to find a row in BOOKING_GRID and then go read the block that has the row in BOOKING_STATES with that ROWID. The catch is, if later on there's another row with a rowid in a block that it's already read before, it's going to re-read that block (sure, it may be cached) to get the other row. Kind of like "open the block, get a row, close the box....then later on open the same box again, get another row, close the box, move on to the next box"

On the other hand, your hash join is:
- sorting the rows in the smaller set (in this case the rows in BOOKING_GRID where hotel=128), put them in memory
- full table scan BOOKING_STATES - and here's the kicker - using multiblock reads. it reads many blocks at a time and processes all of the rows in a block *without* needing to re-read it later. It's like "open the box, process all of the rows in the box, then close the box."

(For more details on the above check out http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28274/optimops.htm, in particular the following sections:

- 11.5.1 Full Table Scans
- 11.5.3.1 Assessing I/O for Blocks, not Rows
- 11.6.3 Nested Loop Joins
- 11.6.4 Hash Joins
  )

By the way, it's a bit curious that it's doing the "access("BG"."HOTEL"=128)" step twice using two indexes -how are the BOOKING_GRIDPK and BOOKING_GRID_INDEX5 indexes defined? You're asking for all columns from both tables, but the plan never touches the BOOKING_GRID table.)

Comment: Yes exactly. Please see my comment at the top.
I understand the different plan is related to the number of rows for each hotel but what I want is to understand why he thinks a "hash with nested loop" should be faster that a "TABLE ACCESS BY USER ROWID". RowID is a direct pointer to the rows of the table, nothing can be faster!

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It is very interesting. I added the information about BOOKING_GRID index. I would be happy to have your feeling about it!

Comment: So joining by rowId is not that good if Oracle reads entire blocks! Do you think there is an optimization I can make by creating new index or should we definitely remove the rowId thing and use other optimization such as BG.hotel=BS.hotel...?

Comment: You should use a proper sequence generated key value. This rowid method is a definite anti-pattern.

Comment: @RenaudBlue - Yes, ROWIDs are the fastest way to get to an individual row, but when dealing with many rows, you need to consider what Oracle's doing with the reads. As David Aldridge says, you shouldn't be using stored rowids anyways as they can change (think "alter table move..."). A surrogate key approach is definitely worth looking at.

Comment: Okay thank you Patrick and David, I will consider all this in the future!